XSLT Replace only specific prefix with another and leave others
Below is my xml, I want XSLT file to replace only "ns2" prefix with "Saa" I want to leave any elements with any other prefix or no prefix as is.
So everywhere where there is ns2:Element it should replace it with Saa:Element e.g. ns2:Revision should be Saa:Revision and so on.
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ns2:DataPDU xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
    <ns2:Revision>2.0.13</ns2:Revision>
    <ns2:Header>
        <ns2:Message>
            <ns2:SenderReference>X</ns2:SenderReference>
            <ns2:MessageIdentifier>Y</ns2:MessageIdentifier>
            <ns2:Format>Z</ns2:Format>
            <ns2:Sender>
                <ns2:DN>DN1</ns2:DN>
            </ns2:Sender>
            <ns2:Receiver>
                <ns2:DN>DN2</ns2:DN>
            </ns2:Receiver>
            <ns2:NetworkInfo>
                <ns2:Service>Service</ns2:Service>
            </ns2:NetworkInfo>
        </ns2:Message>
    </ns2:Header>
    <ns2:Body>
        <head:AppHdr xmlns:head="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">
            <head:Fr>
                <head:FIId>
                    <head:FinInstnId>
                        <head:BICFI>ABC</head:BICFI>
                    </head:FinInstnId>
                </head:FIId>
            </head:Fr>
            <head:To>
                <head:FIId>
                    <head:FinInstnId>
                        <head:BICFI>XYZ</head:BICFI>
                    </head:FinInstnId>
                </head:FIId>
            </head:To>
            <head:BizMsgIdr>123</head:BizMsgIdr>
            <head:MsgDefIdr>P8</head:MsgDefIdr>
            <head:BizSvc>02</head:BizSvc>
            <head:CreDt>2024-07-22</head:CreDt>
        </head:AppHdr>
        <pacs:Document xmlns:pacs="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.08">
            <pacs:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
                <pacs:GrpHdr>
                    <pacs:MsgId>MsgId</pacs:MsgId>
                    <pacs:CreDtTm>2024-07-22</pacs:CreDtTm>
                    <pacs:NbOfTxs>1</pacs:NbOfTxs>
                    <pacs:SttlmInf>
                        <pacs:SttlmMtd>XYZ</pacs:SttlmMtd>
                    </pacs:SttlmInf>
                </pacs:GrpHdr>
        <pacs:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
        </pacs:Document>
    </ns2:Body>
</ns2:DataPDU>


unreliable but simpler sed 's/ns2:/Saa:/g'

I am looking for an XSLT solution

Are you sure? I don't see any XSLT code in the question...

Prefixes are irrelevant and cosmetic. You don't make it clear whether you want to change the namespace, or just to use a different prefix with the same namespace.
